# What is Windows Azure?

Tags: windows, azure

Announced today.  Descriptions so far are confusing.  Let's put together a good starting point for understanding Windows Azure.

Strongly related to [What is a "Cloud OS"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280037/what-is-a-cloud-os), but not enough to warrant closing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Description

The Azure™ Services Platform (Azure) **is an internet-scale cloud services platform hosted in Microsoft data centers**, which provides an operating system and a set of developer services that can be used individually or together. Azure’s flexible and interoperable platform can be used to build new applications to run from the cloud or enhance existing applications with cloud-based capabilities. Its open architecture gives developers the choice to build web applications, applications running on connected devices, PCs, servers, or hybrid solutions offering the best of online and on-premises.

Azure **reduces the need for up-front technology purchases**, and it enables developers to quickly and **easily create applications running in the cloud** by using their existing skills with the Microsoft Visual Studio development environment and the Microsoft .NET Framework. In addition to managed code languages supported by .NET, Azure will support more programming languages and development environments in the near future. Azure simplifies maintaining and operating applications by providing on-demand compute and storage to host, scale, and manage web and connected applications. Infrastructure management is automated with a platform that is designed for high availability and dynamic scaling to match usage needs with the option of a pay-as-you-go pricing model. Azure provides an open, standards-based and interoperable environment with support for multiple internet protocols, including HTTP, REST, SOAP, and XML.

### Features

Key components of the Azure Services Platform include the following:

- Windows Azure for service hosting and management, low-level scalable storage, computation and networking
- Microsoft SQL Services for a wide range of database services and reporting
- Microsoft .NET Services which are service-based implementations of familiar .NET Framework concepts such as workflow and access control
- Live Services for a consistent way for users to store, share and synchronize documents, photos, files and information across their PCs, phones, PC applications and Web sites
- Microsoft SharePoint Services and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Services for business content, collaboration and rapid solution development in the cloud.

Comment: Hoping for something other than the Microsoft-speak...

Comment: Read your question again. Computer is all about having good requirement ;)

Comment: Feel free to edit it so we can collect more helpful information.  I'm not in it for the rep boost.

Comment: The question is fine with me :) Have a nice day and thx to show me Azure, didn't know this service.

Answer (score 4):

It's time sharing. Once again we reinvent something. ;) And who predicted mainframes would die.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be Microsoft's main page:
[Azure Services Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/azure/default.mspx)

Answer (score 1):

**In simple words:**

A Microsoft *services-based operating environment* (also called a cloud computing platform) that will let developers build and host services on Microsoft's infrastructure.

Windows Azure is an *open platform* that support both Microsoft and non-Microsoft languages and environments.

According to the official Microsoft Windows Azure Web site, developers can build their applications and services, developers using Visual Studio 2008 as well as popular standards and protocols including SOAP, REST, and XML.

Answer (score 0):

Azure is a cloud hosting, if we have a web app application we can hosting on it.
Azure also support various script languages (C#, PHP, Phyton etc).
Today Azure also support for wordpress and various databases.
We can subscribe azure by period or "pay as you go".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure is a cloud computing service created by Microsoft for building, deploying, and managing applications and services through a global network of Microsoft-managed data centers. It provides software as a service, platform as a service and infrastructure as a service and supports many different programming languages, tools and frameworks, including both Microsoft-specific and third-party software and systems.Please refer below link to understand Azure-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/microsoft_azure/