# What is a "Cloud OS"?

Tags: windows, cloud, azure

The term is getting 'hotter' with Microsoft Azure and Windows 7.
 What are the benefits + how does the status quo of desktop computing now change? Does the machine no longer need an OS installation (or a highly stripped down version of a typical OS)... what is needed to interact with the 'Cloud' ?

**Update**: Received my first RTFM on SO today.
**To elaborate.. I'm interested in knowing how different is the 'new way' w.r.t. the services provided by a typical desktop OS today** (read Win XP/Vista, linux flavors galore, etc.)... NOT the benefits of cloud computing.

Comment: Seems like there is no difference at the OS level.. just part of the hype. just turn everything into services that run on machine farms managed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 11):

Two buzzwords.

Comment: Actually one buzzword prepended to an established term

Answer (score 5):

Basically its Microsoft's form of competition against Google's recent web-apps boom. So if you want to know what it's all about just open up google docs and gmail, and there you go :)

Now on a personal note, I'm glad Microsoft and Apple(Mobile Me) are trying to fight back against Google. We need the competition, so us the users can choose and get better apps.

Also I'm really not a fan of any corporation, so I'm not all that excited about Google killing off everyone else any more than Microsoft doing the same to others.

Comment: If it's just apps that run off the net like google docs, why the term OS.. i.e my 'XP machine running firefox to view a google spreadsheet' equals 'cloud OS' ?

Comment: Because the Microsoft likely will have its OS be the Browser (=>Explorer opens up the apps and you don't see this happen). Apple does this with Safari's web-apps already. Basically it removes a noticeable layer between app and os. Google Chrome copied the Safari feature, so you can try that out too.

Comment: I would say that's pretty tiny an improvement (a bookmark/shortcut?) to term as a "cloud OS".. but maybe thats what it is. :)

Comment: Well on the desktop side of things thats all you need. The real work is on having scalable web services that work using Cloud-computing principles. That's where it gets tricky

Comment: "Also I'm really not a fan of any corporation, so I'm not all that excited about Google killing off everyone else any more than Microsoft doing the same to others." -- Here here!

Answer (score 2):

When Microsoft says Azure is a Cloud OS, what they mean is that it provides the same kind of services to developers targeting the "Cloud" abstractions that are akin to what a Desktop OS provides developers targeting desktop.

Amitabh Srivistava gave a great interview on Channel 9 explaining it. Basically, if you want to write a notepad application for a desktop user, you don't have to be concerned with writing code that interprets key strokes from the keyboard, or that sets up communications with a printer. This is due to the desktop os. Similarly, Azure lets a developer focus on their cloud app better by abstracting things like load balancing, authentication and authorization, failover, and a lot of concerns that one would normally have to address when developing for the Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Old school network diagrams always showed the internet as a cloud.  Microsofts approach is still a client-server model, although a real 'cloud' os in theory would be a SOA architecture of loosely fit components interconnecting and working together without really being aware of eachother.  Example: creating services for email, document authoring, file storage, etc- which could all be interconnected by different services that don't erally need to be aware of the final product.

So different way of thinking of it: the 'system' exists in the network- not one single location.

Gains: Transparency, redundancy (not only of each service, but for replacing parts if vendors drop out) and availability (as long as you are also connected to the network).

Losses: Vendor lock-ins, vendor's dropping out, interoperability nightmare, as far as I know- there are no real standards for this model.

Microsoft did not coin 'cloud' computing term.  Please refer to the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing) for a more specific definition and etymology.

Answer (score 1):

whats with the RTFM questions on SO lately?  unless I'm missing some deeper meaning, your questions are obvious.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

> Cloud computing is Internet-based
>   ("cloud") development and use of
>   computer technology ("computing"). The
>   cloud is a metaphor for the Internet
>   (based on how it is depicted in
>   computer network diagrams) and is an
>   abstraction for the complex
>   infrastructure it conceals.[1] It is a
>   style of computing in which IT-related
>   capabilities are provided “as a
>   service”,[2] allowing users to access
>   technology-enabled services from the
>   Internet ("in the cloud")[3] without
>   knowledge of, expertise with, or
>   control over the technology
>   infrastructure that supports them.[4]
>   According to a 2008 paper published by
>   IEEE Internet Computing "Cloud
>   Computing is a paradigm in which
>   information is permanently stored in
>   servers on the Internet and cached
>   temporarily on clients that include
>   desktops, entertainment centers, table
>   computers, notebooks, wall computers,
>   handhelds, sensors, monitors, etc."[5]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform

> Microsoft's Azure Services Platform is
>   a cloud platform (cloud computing
>   platform as a service) offering that
>   "provides a wide range of internet
>   services that can be consumed from
>   both on-premises environments or the
>   internet"[1]. It is signficant in that
>   it is Microsoft's first step into
>   cloud computing following the recent
>   launch of the Microsoft Online
>   Services offering.
>   ...
>   The idea and push from Microsoft to
>   compete directly in the software as a
>   service model that Google's Google
>   Docs have offered is increasingly seen
>   by them and others as an important
>   next step in application development.
>   In this idea, a software doesn't have
>   to be installed and managed on the
>   user's computer. It also allows files
>   and folders to be accessed from the
>   web.

Answer (score 0):

So far, it looks like the idea of having software & your data hosted at msft's data centre.
SOA seems to be related to what cloud is offering.

No need to have local software (office will run from internet, your docs will be saved there. so that, you can access it anywhere). I think, the target could be big companies - thereby giving them services (software + hardware (data storage + processing power)) on subscription basis.

An expert can shed light on how this can be useful?
Will people be willing to put everything in the cloud?

Comment: Not interested in the second q.. since that is bound to be subjective.. only time can tell.

Comment: I'm no expert, but it's at least minimally useful in the sense that you no longer need to carry USB memory sticks with documents around, and the fact that theoretically you could use Office even from Linux for example. Both of these premises are nice things to imagine IMHO

Comment: Nice to imagine also is the concept of small and medium businesses operating entirely without an office - if your business services can be accessed from any computer on the net, you don't need a physical presence if you're an online entity (like the company I work for).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud is Time Sharing.  Us old timers remember those days. You either wrote your own apps and ran it on their (the Time Share/Cloud providers) systems or you use the software they supplied. Usually word processors and accounting apps.

Google Apps is cloud. And since you get HD space you can already serve up your own app running on their systems.

Time Share was all the rage in the 70's and 80. Cause maintaining a system of your own wasn't cheap. Back then the smallest system any company ran was a mid-range (like Honeywell, AS400, Dec, etc, etc). Fell out of favor as the PC became popular. I remember  when Lotus 1-2-3 came out and everyone predicted it would destroy what was left of Time Sharing. And it (along with dBase and other aps) did.

It's funny how we re-invite everything.

PS: Forgot one thing about Time Sharing. Since the Net wasn't around, you had to schedule your time. SO your staff would go to the providers Data Center and work. It was like renting space and the systems. Time Share and Cloud operate differently, but the function is the same.

Comment: One of the major differences between 70-80's era time-sharing and cloud computing is that now the time is being sliced into nanoseconds instead of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Well like many new terms, there can be more than one answer.  Frequently it can be defined as a compute platform, where the developer doesn't have to worry about resource management, scalability or hardware failures, because the cloud infrastructure handles it.  Here is a link to some information the company I work for has:

http://www.appistry.com/resource-library/index.html

There are some good white papers linked here that might be helpful to you.

-Brett

Answer (score 0):

A cloud operating system primarily manages the operation of one or more virtual machines within a virtualized environment.

Microsoft Windows Azure and Google Chrome OS are among current examples of cloud operating systems.

Azure App Service is one of the common and most used services. While it is possible to immediately deploy apps, jobs etc., to the app service, a common factor that baffles decision makers is the wide spectrum of the tiers (options of plans) available in the marketspace. To know more details,visit:https://www.impigertech.com/blog/azure-app-service/