# What is Azure and .NET Services? Is there any correlation with WCF Services?

Tags: .net, wcf, azure

What is Azure and .NET Services? Is there any correlation with WCF Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure is Microsoft's cloud computing environment - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240455/what-is-windows-azure#240533).

Re WCF: is certainly one the the things you can *host* in the cloud, but you can do a lot more too...

(wiki'd, as ***close*** to a dup, but not 100% dup...)

Comment: thanks for the link and for the explanation!
I gave you the points!
Bye

Comment: No you didn't; I wiki'd it because it was so close to an existing answer ;-p

Answer (score 1):

Azure is sometimes referred to as Microsoft Azure which is a public cloud computing service created by Microsoft for developing, testing, deploying, and managing applications.

.Net is a framework of software that is also created by Microsoft that runs on Microsft Windows.

WCF is abbreviated as Windows Communication Foundation which is a framework used to enable hosting services in any type of operating system process. Mostly it is used along with .Net

For a better understanding, I would suggest you go through some resources like [MS Azure Tutorial](https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/microsoft-azure-tutorial/), .Net tutorial that may help a beginner.