# Azure vs Web API

Tags: performance, azure, service, asp.net-web-api

There are many articles about Azure like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240455/what-is-windows-azure).

But all those words **are** still **pretty general**. Yes, that's clear that Azure is cloud etc. and so on.

However, still, **what** could I get from moving my (let's say, even mobile services) from Web API implementation to Azure in **my particular application** (services)?

**What are the exact benefits**? All the same but a bit more convenient and reliable?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I understand of Azure in that meaning (for instance, comparing it to Amazon EC2 (like)). But what's about services... like "web" or "mobile" - why is it for? That sounds like really some additional services... Because MS says: "you can use those to build mobile applications" (backend), so what, I also can do that with Web API -- what are actually the benefits?

Comment: It has API because it isn't just Hosting. It is MS's effort to combine many of the needed back-end technologies to support a wide range of Web Solutions;the map here gives a better visualization for what it contains: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163896.aspx. Web API is just a framework for setting up client-server communications, it is not mutually exclusive to Azure (and in fact there is a tutorial for hosting Web API on Azure: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role).

Comment: Ok. I hear what you are saying. But still, if I have some mobile application and also that application uses some backend build on Web API, what benefits can I achieve if I rebuild my backend to use Azure instead? (Could you provide at least several life-time examples for better understanding?) Would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still learning myself (prepping for the MCSD in Web applications) and my company doesn't use Azure, so I don't have a real world example of use. And you really wouldn't be rebuilding your backend per say, but deploying your code to the cloud rather than setting up a server yourself.

Comment: :) I am surely not going to rebuilt. But an example of what I would get if I would have rebuilt it, would help much. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @scrappedcola - Azure's not a hosting service, and it's certainly not specific to IIS.

Comment: @David Makogon I guess scrappedcola meant that already that that's *not only* a hosting service (but basically it is. no?). And he also mentioned IIS in meaning, that Azure provides everything which IIS can provide (isn't that also right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite clear as to what you are asking, because you can take your Web API application and host it on Windows Azure as a Cloud Service or as a Web Site.

Can you clarify what you mean by Azure vs. Web API?

Edit:

If you are looking to move an existing application I would go for the Web Site. Its simple and would allow you to on board Windows Azure with a minimum of changes.

benefits from moving to mobile services is everything that comes with the platform. By building your services using mobile services you will have access to push notifications, scalability, updates made by microsoft to the platform and so forth.

if you application is already in production, I would first move to web sites and then see what your needs are.

Comment: Actually, I am asking exactly because I don't fully get the Azure. In know about Azure hosting (cloud). But there are also, for instance, Azure for mobile services. There is also Azure SDK (which, obviosly considers some services (functionality)) etc. So, all that seems for me not just like uploading to Azure the same way as Amazon. (So, I am asking about definite differences I would be able to use as a .NET developer with Azure using, not just having my Web API as a services for my mobile apps).

Comment: Yes. I am not going to move... I just want to understand what that would be the difference if I would have built my backend services on Azure mobile (for instance), but not Web API.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want to know what are the main features about mobile services. Am I right?

Mobile servers are a easy way to build a backend for your mobile apps. It also offers Push notifications, which allow you to send notifications to any device (ios, android, wp). But if you won't need that, you can use just your webapi.

Take a look at this overview of a lot of features that Azure offers too:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/fundamentals/intro-to-windows-azure/

Comment: Kind of general explanation (similar to all those links available through the net), but reading carefully the link info has brought a bit more light to the questions.